# Gravatar for user post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

I was wondering where could I put a HTML IMG tag so I can put the image HERE:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilAdG.png

I've been trying with PHP but I don't know which file to edit (I've tried putting it in Single.php)

Here's the blog:

http://rohelpers.pusku.com/

Comment: Are you trying to replace the theme's date image for the post with the user's gravatar?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have an image for the date...So no.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to replace from the image as it looks very different from the blog you linked to. Can you link a better example?

Comment: That picture I've posted it's an example of what I want to add in that empty space, I added it in Photoshop. That's what I WANT to GET.

Comment: Okay, I've found an example. http://www.transformaps.fr/, I want THIS http://i.imgur.com/7X2Bwtl.png

Comment: The changes here are likely to be theme specific so you'll either have to provide a link to the theme you are using or provide the theme files somehow.